# Is it okay to implement multiple design patterns?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm currently developing a school project and we are instructed that we are required to implement Object-Oriented Programming concepts in our software. But I don't want to implement it just by simply inheriting this class to that class and overriding this method to implement its own functionality and so on. Though it is still acceptable but I want to do it differently. By differently, I mean by using design patterns. I'm trying to understand it one by one and I noticed that some of them are very useful(Builder, Memento and Adapter). But the problem is there are so many of them and if possible I want to put/implement it all(those 3 design pattern). Is it okay if I do that? Would it mess up the project as a whole?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As always: It depends.

Overusage of patterns on small and simple bits of code can obscure the code. But it can also make it more clear.

Don't use patterns wherever possible. Use them when it serves a purpose. Every pattern has its purpose and if you can't find that purpose in your code, you shouldn't rewrite it to match a pattern. Try to keep your code a) maintainable and b) easy to read. If a pattern fulfills these criteria more than your approach without patterns: go for it.

You can have code with dozens of patterns and code with none. In both cases it can be the ideal choice.